# Books on higher dimensional elementary differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, book-recommendation, surfaces

I am looking for information on hypersurfaces embedded $\mathbb{R}^n (n>3)$, mostly on their curvature and second fundamental form. Most books I have looked at only contain information on surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and then jump straight to abstract surfaces (generall manifolds) where everything is too abstract for me. I'd like to learn how to state/describe the curvature of a hypersurface in the most elementary way possible. Are there any (somewhat) modern books that give a nice reference on this topic? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at Thorpe's book *Elementary Topics in Differential Geometry*. It does hypersurfaces quite generally throughout.

Comment: Here are some books:
Gallot, Hulin, Lafontaine, Riemannian Geometry. Petersen, Riemannian Geometry. Besse, Einstein Manifolds. Introduction to Riemannian geometry, Lee.

Comment: @Didier But these are all graduate Riemannian geometry texts. If you read what OP said, he doesn't want to do all the machinery of manifolds and wants a concrete treatment.